# Calculating a complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis

How can I calculate $$\int_{|z-i|=1}\frac{1}{z+i}\;dz$$

It seems like the non-continuous point is: $z=-i$, and it is not inside the contour, would that mean that the integral is simply zero?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes

**Hint** : Use Cauchy-Goursat Theorem

Answer (score 0):

YES,
Cauchy integral theorem,or u can use that 
this is a holomorphic function which can define on a convex set contains this contour so it accept an orginal function F,so the integral is F(i+1)-F(i+1)=0

Answer (score -1):

Cauchy Integral formula gives us
\begin{align}
f(a) = \oint_\gamma \dfrac{f(z)}{z-a} \,dz
\end{align}

Let $f(z) = 1 \; \forall z \in \mathbb{C}$, so, you are evaluating $f(-i)$, which by our definition is 1.